# vba types incompatible while comparing two strings

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I want to compare two strings from two different worksheets with vba in excel. Already wrote the following code:

```
Public Sub Vergleich_Arbeitsmappen()
Dim i As Long
Dim projectCounter As Integer
Dim strAngNr As String
Dim strCodename As String



Dim wks As Workbook

strAngNr = Range("C3").Value
strCodename = Range("C4").Value
projectCounter = 200

Set wks = Workbooks.Open("filename")

For i = 2 To projectCounter
    
    If CStr(Workbooks(wks).Worksheets("Tabelle2").Cells(i, 2).Value) = strAngNr Then
        MsgBox "FEHLER"
        
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

But while debugging, excel always show the error "types incompatible" even if both values are strings, as defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem doesn't come from the 2 strings you are comparing, it comes from the invalid parameter into the `Workbooks`-collection.
As you have Workbook object already stored in `wks`, you simply can write

```
wks.Worksheets("Tabelle2").Cells(i, 2).Value
```

You use the `Workbooks`-Collection to access an open workbook either by name or by index so the parameter into Workbooks is either a String or a Number (In theory you could write `Workbooks(wks.Name)`, but that would be completely useless).

You are passing an object of type `Workbook` as Parameter, and that fails and give you the "types incompatible"-error.